# How to get Lines to the Left and Right of Centered Div - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have three `divs` within a div like this:

```
<div class="row second-top-margin">
    <div class="col-md-12 center">
        <div class="center-text">Responsive</div>
        <div class="center-text">Clean</div>
        <div class="center-text">Powerful</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is get lines, vertically aligned center, to the left and right of the word clean, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this with CSS? I've tried quite a bit of different things. I tried to put the left line, "Clean" and the right line all within three separate divs, within a new div called `table` and made them `display: table-cell`, but "Clean" no longer displayed in center when I got rid of the `display: inherit` style.

Please see my JS fiddle to see where I am:

https://jsfiddle.net/do4L2g4L/2/

Any suggestions? Thanks!

P.S. I realize the lines are `border-bottom` right now - I'll need to vertical align them center, I was just trying to get them to the left and right of "Clean" for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Don't use `display:table` to center items. It stopped being ok 20 years ago</del>.
I tend to regard `display:table` as misused (a dirty hack) when used for centering (it's better than just using a `<table>` element for the task, which is far worse, but still a misuse).  A simple...

```
.between-lines {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

... will do. Updated example (taken from fiddle):

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inherit;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.between-lines {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 0;
}

.clean {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 52px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

body {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row second-top-margin">
  <div class="col-md-12 center">
    <div class="center-text">Responsive</div>
    <div class="between-lines">

      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="clean">Clean</div>
      <div class="line"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="center-text">Powerful</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** I replaced `table` class with `between-lines` because `table` already has some styling in Bootstrap and from the looks of it, you're using it.

**Final note:** If you're not using deployment tools with integrated prefixing, consider running your CSS through [autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) before pushing it live.

---

Here's a version that doesn't allow the lines to grow on wide screens and vertically centers the lines on an area having viewport's height. If you don't want that, remove the `height: 100vh` from `.center`:

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
  margin: 0;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 52px;
}

.between-lines {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 0;
}

.clean {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row second-top-margin">
  <div class="col-lg-12 center">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="center-text">Responsive</div>
      <div class="between-lines">

        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="clean">Clean</div>
        <div class="line"></div>

      </div>
      <div class="center-text">Powerful</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, `<table>` stopped being OK (for non-tabular data) a while back, but `display:table` is perfectly fine (maybe not the best solution for this problem, but perfectly fine).

Comment: Not according to my point of view, @Scott. `display:table` is for displaying tabular data, not for layout-ing. If it was used correctly, browsers would have already implemented default pagination, sorting, filtering or show/hide/reorder columns or even formulas out of the box for `display:table` elements. But they haven't and they are not going to anytime soon. Why? Because people still use it for centering, instead of using it for displaying tabular data.

Comment: *"If it was used correctly, browsers would have already implemented default pagination, sorting and filtering out of the box"* Why would you think that? Browsers don't implement that behavior for table content because HTML is static and not designed for this, that's what JavaScript is for.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Quite a few HTML5 features (think `<input type="number">`, or form element validation behavior, not to mention media objects) are proof your statement is becoming one only true for past versions of html. Having some default functionality/behavior already defined on some elements doesn't mean you can't disable it and set your own. But I really don't see a reason why all I mentioned in previous comment shouldn't be available in future versions of `HTML` for `display:table` elements.

Comment: There's a very big difference between those examples and data sorting, filtering and pagination. The former is about content, the latter is about display and functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation. The only problem I have left is shrinking the width of the lines on either side of "clean". I tried giving `line` a specific width in pixels and percentage, but nothing happened: 

https://jsfiddle.net/do4L2g4L/7/

Comment: @Happy, all you need to do is wrap it all inside an element that will limit the component's width and keep it centered. I'll add an example to the answer. Love your chosen SO name. :)

Comment: You're a genius. Have a happy night!

Comment: [`display:table` hadn't even been invented 20 years ago](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-CSS2-971104/flowobj.html#didx-display)

Comment: Correct, @Alohci. It was an exaggeration. But let's break it down: `<table>` for centering is bad, but `display:table` is OK? Is this what everyone's trying to tell me? From my POV, `display:table` enables the `<table>` behavior and structure, with some limitations, on any DOM element. Why would I want to apply that for centering? And why does everyone think it's OK-ish? I totally dig `display:table` on `<div>`s replacing `<table>`s to make it easier to apply responsiveness, but to use it for centering... I tend to see that as a dirty hack. A misuse. Am I wrong?

Comment: The reason that the use of `<table>` is generally considered "taboo" these days is because of people using this tag for content that is not actually tabular. This means that the semantics of the tag are incorrect for the content and given that the HTML parser is slower to process tables than normal block or inline elements, the misuse of `table` becomes a big "no no". But, when tabular data is the content, then `<table>` is not only OK, it the preferred because it is the correct semantics for the content.  Unfortunately, most developers don't understand all this and just believe that all ....

Comment: ...references to table (HTML or CSS) should be avoided and that is not the case. While it's inappropriate to use `<table>` for non-tabular content, the use of `display:table` in CSS on any content is perfectly fine and this is for two reasons: 1) we're now talking about styling, not semantics 2) the CSS rendering engine can process table layouts faster than the HTML parser can.

Comment: I would even go so far as to say that the use of `display:table` on `div` elements that are creating a table structure is incorrect and you should be using `<table>` because you lose the proper semantics with `<div>`. HTML (especially HTML5) is all about semantics.

Comment: You've hit the soft spot, @Scott, I agree with what you said and I usually use `<table>`s for tabular data. I recently had to code a complex case of tabular data display for a large chain of grocery stores. The design was so that when a product row was selected it would detach from the rest, visually breaking the table, get a significant shadow and open up in material design style. Had to choose between `<table>` and `<div>`s. I stuck with `<table>`, even though it meant adding/removing empty spacer rows on the fly for the material effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    }

     .center-text {
     color: #ffffff;
     display: inherit;
     font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 52px;
     }

    .table {
    display:table;
    }
    .clean {
     display: -webkit-box !important;
    }
    hr {
    display: table;
    width: 60%;
     }

    .line {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
     display: table-cell;
     }

    .clean {
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    }

    body {
    background: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row second-top-margin">
        <div class="col-md-12 center">
            <div class="center-text">Responsive</div>
            <div class="table">
            
              <div class="line"></div>
              <div class="clean"><hr>Clean<hr></div>
              <div class="line"></div>
              
            </div>
            <div class="center-text">Powerful</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Picture]

Comment: I have edited your answer so that your code can be executed here in Stack Overflow and you can clearly see that your code does not produce what the screen shot shows.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus. To be honest, I'm a newbie in stackoverflow. I still don't know how to use code snippet :D

Comment: I already updated my code. Please check again. I just missed to put @important in the CSS that I added. I apologize.

Comment: Wow. Just missed 1 line then voted negative. Seriously? Could you ask me first to check my code before doing that? I can't believe it.

Comment: I'll retract the down vote when the code works. Even now, the horizontal alignment is off. Also, a good Stack Overflow answer contains more than just working code, it contains an explanation of the answer as well.

Comment: Also, `!important` is widely known to be a "no-no" when it comes to good CSS design. It makes the code more difficult to debug and is almost always not needed (just re-thinking your selectors usually allows you to not have to use it).

Comment: alright. Well, I will consider this as a way to improve myself and see this positively. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is semantics. Use `span` elements for this kind of content, rather than `div` elements because, although the three lines of content are on different lines, they are part of the same thought/idea. So, they should all be contained in a `div`, but each part *spans* part of that `div`. Usually, the less complex the structure, the easier to style. After removing the unnecessary stuff and simple CSS for the rest does the trick. No `display:table` is necessary.

```css
body {
   background: #000000;
}

.center { text-align: center; }

.line {
     display:inline-block;
     width:15%;
     vertical-align:middle;
}

.box {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_ltsemibold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 52px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.col-md-12 { display:inline-block; width:75%;  margin:auto; }
```

```html
<div class="row second-top-margin center box">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <span>Responsive</span>
     <br>
     <span class="line"><hr></span>
     <span>Clean</span>
     <span class="line"><hr></span>
     <br>
     <span>Powerful</span>
  </div>
</div>
```